# USB camera to composite video out

Tags: usb, camera

I have an USB camera (640 x 480) that I would like to present on composite video out (live). Is there a way to get it fully automated? I mean, when powering up the Raspberry it should start up the program and present the video out - that's the only thing the Rasberry should do...

I've tried with MK-linux since RaspberryOs doesn't recognize the camera. In MK-linux I've used guvcview to get picture and that's working. So what I've struggling to get to work is to make the system boot up and automaticly start up guvcview in full screen (640 x 480) with only picture - no toolbars or anything, just picture... that's all it should do but can't get it to work. MK-linux is also a little too "heavy", would like it to be slim and quick start so perhaps someone have a better suggestion?

Comment: `systemd` can do that for you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `ffmpeg` can stream video for you

Comment: I've edited the question with more information